# Connect interface builder component to IBOutlet that is a property of a class outside of any instance of a view controller?

Tags: ios

I have a project that is a color picker. For each color component, red, green, and blue, I have a UIPickerView, a textField, and a stepper. What I want to do is create a class, let's call it ColorPickerObject that looks like this

```
@interface ColorPickerObject : NSObject {
IBOutlet UITextField  *colorTextField;
IBOutlet UIStepper    *colorStepper;
IBOutlet UIPickerView *colorPicker;
         int          colorIntegerValue;
         NSArray      *valuesForComponent1InColorPicker;
         NSArray      *valuesForComponent2InColorPicker;
         NSArray      *valuesForComponent3InColorPicker;
}

@property IBOutlet UITextField  *colorTextField;
@property IBOutlet UIStepper    *colorStepper;
@property IBOutlet UIPickerView *colorPicker;
@property          int          colorIntegerValue;
@property          NSArray      *valuesForComponent1InColorPicker;
@property          NSArray      *valuesForComponent2InColorPicker;
@property          NSArray      *valuesForComponent3InColorPicker;
@end
```

Then, I have a colorPickerBrain that looks like this,

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ColorPickerObject.h"

@interface ColorPickerBrain : NSObject {
ColorPickerObject *red,
                  *green,
                  *blue;

}

//@property ColorPickerObject *red;
//@property ColorPickerObject *green;
//@property ColorPickerObject *blue;
@end
```

and for reference my colorPickerViewController, (not sure if this helps or is relevant to the issue)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ColorPickerBrain.h"

@interface ColorPickerViewController : UIViewController {
ColorPickerBrain *brain;
}

- (IBAction)redChanged:( id )sender;
- (IBAction)greenChanged:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)blueChanged:(id)sender;
@end
```

I have all of the UI components laid out on the story board but I am unsure how to connect them to the outlets defined in the ColorPickerObject. How can I connect these UIcomponents in my story board to the outlets defined in ColorPickerObject through the brain instance created in my view controller that has a red, green, and blue ColorPickerObject.

I am new to ios, this is technically my first app and I have no idea what to even look for. Everything I have found talks about connecting components in a base class that is an instance of a UIView but this base class isn't view based. I am coming from Java if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect the outlet with the storyboard in Seven easy steps. Check out the images blow which display the steps...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much That is almost exactly what I was looking for. I have three instances of the ColorPickerObject. One red, green, and blue contained in the colorPickerBrain. How can I reference the text field on the story board to be the member of that ColorPickerObject for each of the three objects. I can only have the textfield outlet in my colorPickerObject represent a single item by dragging the connections. I need to be able to reference the IBOutlet in the ColorPickerObject for each of the three color picker objects contained in ColorPickerBrain.

Comment: Does not understand actually what you want. Why you want to create Different textfield connection for red, green, and blue. instance that the instance of the object class so it will have its UItextfield connection.

Comment: I want to have a textfield, a stepper, and a UIPickerView for each color. I wrapped it in a class so that I can create three objects that all have their reference to the story board components.

Comment: If I bring the object ColorPickerObject into the storyboard I can easily reference the IBOutlet UITextField with the instructions previously given. However, I can only have one textfield represented by this outlet. I want this outlet to be represented through the red ColorPickerObject so that I can do the same for green and blue.

Comment: What I did was, in interface builder I dragged out three ColorPickerObject objects and just set the outlets for each of those three, then I brought out a ColorPickerBrain object and connected its' red, green, and blue references to the three color picker objects I created in the story board. Would that be the correct way to set this up the way I want?

Comment: Actually what is your requirement can you explain that to me. On the button click in your ViewControllr you want to change the value of the Red Green And blue is that right and add that value in the object is that correct?

Comment: The assignment is pretty much open because this is an android class and I am the only one doing ios (wanted to do something unfamiliar). There actually is no button. The best way to put it is I want to display three components(red, green, and blue). Think of each of these components having their own textField, picker, and stepper. So in total I will have 3 pickers, 3 textfields, and 3 steppers. All of these items in a component due the same thing change the value of either red, green, or blue value in the color displayed in a textview ( using set background ) in my view controller class.